# Is there a way in SQL to select all days available in a table with a 30 days difference jump?

Tags: sql, date, days

I need to select all dates, from current date, with a 30 days jump between each other in the past.
In example, today is October 18th, so I would need to get September 18th , August 19th, July 20th.

I cannot simply write the function current_date - 30, current_date - 60, current_date - 90 because the beginning of the data is far.

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product and date/time functions are highly vendor specific. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Your question is quite vague. I do not know what the beginning of date is? And I do not know what you are trying to achieve? Please elaborate and give proper explanation. You could use an example and sample data to explain much better. In addition, please specify the DBMS you are using

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Oracle you can use below code -

```
WITH DATES(CUR_DATE, MON) AS (SELECT CURRENT_DATE CUR_DATE, 1 MON FROM DUAL
                                UNION ALL
                                SELECT D.CUR_DATE - 30, D.MON + 1 
                                FROM DATES D
                                WHERE TO_CHAR(D.CUR_DATE, 'MM') > 1
                                AND TO_CHAR(D.CUR_DATE, 'YY') = TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'YY'))
SELECT * FROM DATES
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=fcf9bede30bb198c4b5201d34bf38fe9) is the fiddle. For other DBs please post your DBMS product.

Answer (score 0):

For SQL Server, you can use the code below:

```
;WITH cte_Date30Days(n, d, dte) 
AS (
    SELECT 0, 0, current_timestamp as dte
    UNION ALL
    SELECT n+1, d - 30, dateadd(day, -30, dte)
    FROM    
        cte_Date30Days
    WHERE n < 7-1
)
SELECT  dte FROM cte_Date30Days;
```

Only 7 rows are returned but change that value to suit your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Postgres this is quite easy using `generate_series()`

```
select d::date as "date"
from generate_series(current_date, 
                     current_date - interval '1 year', 
                     interval '-1 month') as t(d)
```

That returns the "last 12 months" starting from today.

If today is 2019-10-18, this returns:

```
date      
----------
2019-10-18
2019-09-18
2019-08-18
2019-07-18
2019-06-18
2019-05-18
2019-04-18
2019-03-18
2019-02-18
2019-01-18
2018-12-18
2018-11-18
2018-10-18
```

If you want 30 days intervals (rather than 1 month), use:

```
select d::date as date
from generate_series(current_date, 
                     current_date - interval '1 year', 
                     interval '-30 day') as t(d)
```